# Change legends for range in grouped bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting a grouped bar chart for the following sample dataset.

```
  Group Age
1  G1    29
2  G2    25
3  G3    55
4  G2    33
5  G1    70
6  G3    80
```

In my plot, each group has some Age range and I am using the following syntax.

```
df<- mutate(df, Age_class = cut(LPA_CN, breaks = c(0, 20, 30, 35, 40, 80)))
```

However, the legend in the plot shows `(0,20], (20,30], (30, 35], (35, 40] and (40, 80]`. Is there a way to make it `(0,20) (21,30) (30, 35) (35, 40) and (40, 80)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you would need to provide your custom labels to `cut` -

```
library(dplyr)

df <- mutate(df, Age_class = cut(LPA_CN, breaks = c(0, 20, 30, 35, 40, 80), 
                labels = c('(0,20)', '(21,30)', '(30, 35)', '(35, 40)', '(40, 80)')))
```